# laravel env method get different value when code not change ？

Tags: laravel, google-chrome-devtools, laravel-5.1

I'm new beginner of laravel.I want use Helpers to get environment value using env method.

```
class Helpers {
  public static function somefunc(){
    var_dump(env('QINIU_BUCKET_DOMAIN'));exit;
  }
}
```

Then strange thing happed.When I opened chrome-dev-tool (F12),I got nothing. Then I closed chrome-dev-tool,I got what I want. Is anything wrong? Anybody can help me? :)

Comment: my chrome version is 45.0.2454.101 m

Answer (score -1):

Laravel's .env manages configuration for the **server side environment**.
So, you opening and closing Chrome Dev Tools has nothing to do with this!

You might have changed something in the server environment.
So restarting your server might help.

Check the documentation - http://laravel.com/docs/5.1#configuration